# What does $\mathbb{1}_n$ stand for in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

**Context:**

Let $A$ be a row-stochastic matrix, i.e., a non-negative matrix in which all rows sum to one.

Under certain conditions (not important here), the following is true:

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x(k)=(w^Tx(0))\mathbb{1}_n$,

where $x(k)$ is a discrete-time averaging system; $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $w \geq 0$; $\mathbb{1}_n^Tw=1$; and $w^TA=w^T$.

**Question:**

My textbook (Bullo's lecture notes) uses $I_n$ to represent the identity matrix, so my question is: what does $\mathbb{1}_n$ represent?

Comment: Could it be the vector of all ones of length $n$?

Comment: The vector of all $1$s, e.g. $\mathbb{1}_5 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense given the context

Comment: Note that under the above comments' suggestion, the two equations involving $1_n$ say "For every $i$, $\lim_{k\to\infty} x(k)_i = \sum_j w_jx(0)_j$" and "$\sum_j w_j = 1$".  Without seeing the context, these are at least reasonable interpretations.